# Нужно каждые 12 часов менять значение переменной на 1

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Нужно, чтобы каждые 12 часов от определённого времени переменная увеличивалась на 1

У меня есть таймер который по окончанию выводит сообщение (переменную из текстового файла с помощью php в массив), хочу сделать так, чтоб не надо было постоянно переписывать в текстовый документ строку, а чтобы по окончанию таймера, каждый раз выводилась новая переменная (следовательно другая строка из txt).

Для этого хочу сделать цикл php каждые 12 часов прибавлять переменной 1 и будет показываться следующий элемент из текстового документа.

Comment: запишите в файл время начала, вычисляйте разницу и из неё текущее значение вашей переменной.

Comment: а я не новичок, но ничего не понял. Опишите саму задачу, а не циклы и таймеры

Comment: если у вас есть php, значит где-то скорее всего можно поставить (или уже стоит) cron, сделать маленький файл и создать задачу на запуск файла каждые 12 часов. В файле будет типа открыть файл, прочитать число, прибавить 1, закрыть файл. Все

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте составить для начала правильное условия для запуска,а далее выполнения самого тела скрипта. Если он у вас готов,то начните с цикла.

Answer (score 1):

Эта задача детерминирована, не стоит заниматься её моделированием в реальном времени. Вы в любой момент можете рассчитать каким бы было значение счётчика, если бы вы действительно проводили все эти операции.

1. Определяемся с датой/временем старта
   `$start = strtotime('2017-04-15 11:00:00');`
2. Получаем текущую дату/время
   `$now = time();`
3. Вычисляем значение нашего счётчика
   `$i = floor(($now - $start) / (12*3600));`

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/tHAaB)